# Getting MiddleClick to open on log in for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mouse

I'd like [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/) to open on startup for Mac OS X (10.6.6). I know that you can right-click and select the option, "Open on login" or something like that, but I don't see that option when I right-click the file. Also, when it's run, it doesn't how up in the dock, just in the menu bar.

I tried this commandline option that didn't seem to work either.

Does anyone have any tips?

Also, if you've got middle click on your Magic Trackpad, let me know! I'd love some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose "Open on login" from the dock, you're just editing login items, which can easily be managed in System Preferences.

Open System Preferences -> Accounts, and click the Login Items tab for your username. Then click the plus button at the bottom of the list to find and add MiddleClick.